# Is the novell.directory.ldap c# library allready preventing ldap injection or do I have to encode potential user input by myself?

Tags: c#, ldap, code-injection

im currently developing a user interface to manage users and stuff. As data store I have to use a ldap. I'm using the [`novell.directory.ldap` library](https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/?page=/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/cnet/data/bovumfi.html) for ldap related things.

I'm now wondering if this library already does encoding of parameters it is receiving, e.g. when performing a search, or if I have to encode potential user input, like usernames which will be later used in searchqueries, by myself.

I've already tried to do encoding with the [AntiXSSLibrary](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpl) (I'm using the nuget package sicne the ldap encoding was not included in the .net Framework itself like the other parts of the library) and its `Encoder.LdapFilterEncode()` and `Encoder.LdapDistinguishedNameEncode()` methods.

This is my code when trying to encode:

```
    public static LdapSearchResults PerformSearch(LdapConnection connection, string filter, string basedn)
    {
        string encodedFilter = Encoder.LdapFilterEncode(filter);
        string encodedBasedn = Encoder.LdapDistinguishedNameEncode(basedn);
        LdapSearchConstraints searchConstraints = new LdapSearchConstraints { BatchSize = 0 };
        return connection.Search(encodedBasedn, LdapConnection.SCOPE_SUB, encodedFilter, null, false, searchConstraints);
    }
```

- If I pass the parameters directly (= not encoded) everything will work as expected.
- If I pass the encoded filter I will receive a `LdapLocalException` with message "Filter Error" at the `Search()` method of the `LdapConnection` instance.
- If I pass the unencoded filter and pass the encoded basedn I will receive a `LdapException` with message "Invalid DN syntax" when trying to access the search results.
- If I pass the unencoded filter and pass the ecoded basedn, in this case encoded with the `Encoder.LdapFilterEncode()` method, everything will work fine.

So the central question is: Do I have to worry about ldap injection or is the library already taking care about this threat? Unfortunately I couldn't find an answer for this in the documentation and by searching the web.

If I have to encode (what I'm expecting I have to do at the moment) what is the easiest and safest way to encode inputs for ldap in C#/.Net when the AntiXSSLibrary is not working for me?